SMD connector soldermask opening size
I was reviewing the Samtec-provided KiCAD footprints for their 0.5 mm pitch LSHM connectors and noticed they completely remove the soldermask and in a strange way (note rounded corners) that suggests that maybe they intended some of the mask to be present between the pads:

They make no recommendations about the mask in the datasheet. Looking at a few other 0.5 mm pitch boards I have on hand, none do this.  My concern is that this is going to lead to bridging during reflow, am I right to think this is a mistake?  If so, is there a recommended amount of soldermask I should be including?  Looking at other similar footprints, most leave about 200 microns of soldermask between pads, with zero to 2 mils of bare board around the copper.

In all likelihood, this is just a fixed expansion of the soldermask opening with a 0.1 mm radius (or whatever) out from the pads. This is something that's very easy to do in KiCad by just setting the footprint soldermask expansion parameter. You can likewise do the same for a paste pullback.
Historically, it wasn't uncommon for cheaper fabs to be unable to put such narrow soldermask webbing between pads, so you might even be required to have no soldermask between the pads. I know PCBway*, at least, is perfectly fine with it these days, though.
*No affiliation other than as a customer; I haven't had this kind of fine-pitch board done at any other fab before.

You were right, the solder mask extension for each pad was set to 4 mils.  I didn't realize that KiCAD had that as per-pad property.  I reduced it to 1 mil and it looks more reasonable.

@user1850479 It's actually a multi-level property. You can set a board-wide expansion, which can then be overridden by a per-footprint property, which can then be overridden by a per-pad property.
